# Which project provides the terminal emulator used by the bash from Git for Windows?

Tags: cygwin, msysgit, msys, mingw-w64

I am having a problem* with the `bash` that comes with [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/).

But I don't even know where to start looking/googling/reporting the bug.

It seems that all of MINGGW64 (= MinGW-w64?), MSYS, Cygwin and maybe Mintty are somehow involved, but I don't really understand the relationships between them.

Which one is providing the terminal?

---

* It ignores the VT100 escape sequence sent by `echo -e '\033[?1h'` which should put the cursor keys in "application mode" (= make them send `<ESC>OA` instead of `<ESC>[A`).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have already found, if not

https://mintty.github.io/